# Movie about a company that removes people's souls

Tags: story-identification, movie, souls

The movie I watched was about a company that had some sort of machine that would remove people's souls out of their bodies. The soul would appear as a physical object. People went to this company willingly, knowing what the machine does. After the soul removal, the person would still act like a normal person, but would be unable to feel certain emotions (Which I think was the selling point of this company). I think the movie involves a man who wants to get his soul back into his body after subjecting himself to the process. There was also a scene where a woman gets her soul removed and then, after seeing what it looks like as a physical object, exclaims "It's a chickpea!".

Anyone know what the movie is?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps this could be [Cold Souls](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1127877/)? The synopsis and plot from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_Souls) match a few of your points: there's a company that removes people's souls; the removal of the soul leaves people emotionless; the main character wants to get his soul back from the company.

> Giamatti stars as a fictionalised version of himself, an anxious, overwhelmed actor who decides to enlist the service of a company to deep freeze his soul. Complications ensue when his soul gets lost in a soul trafficking scheme which has taken his soul to St. Petersburg. The film then follows Giamatti desperately trying to recover his soul.

Wikipedia mentions the soul looking like a chickpea, although it's Paul's soul that comes out like a chickpea rather than the normal grey matter, not a woman's soul:

> On visiting the clinic he discovers that most souls come out as gray matter or clouds. He decides to go ahead, declining the offer to look at his soul as it happens. He is distressed to discover that **his soul comes out looking just like a chickpea**.

Comment: Yep, it definitely is.